# How to show that a continuous map on a compact metric space must fix some non-empty set.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness

> Suppose $(X,d)$ is a compact metric space and $f:X\to X$ a continuous map. Show that $f (A)=A$ for some nonempty $A\subseteq X.$

I start this by supposing that $A_0:=X$ and $A_{n+1}:=f(A_n)$ for all $n \geq 0$. If $A_n=A_ {n+1}$ for some $n$ then the purpose is done. But if not, how can we think further?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry but question as it stands does not make any sense.  Are you trying to say something about the limiting behaviour of $A_n$?  Are you trying to approximate an attractor of some sort?

Comment: @muzzlator "Show that $f(A)=A$ for some nonempty $A$ subset of $X$" makes sense for me.

Comment: @julien It makes sense to me too, I don't know how but I must have completely missed that line when I first read it

Comment: @muzzlator: It got added after the initial post, but before the initial $5$-minute free-editing period expired.

Comment: Which definition of compactness do you use in your class, Anindya? Is it the one about convergent sub-sequences, or the one about open covers? My answer gives hints for both definitions, but just curious which one you are using.

Comment: $ A_n $ satisfy finite intersection property on compact set .so their intersection $ A $ is non empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, show that each of your $A_n$ is closed in $X$.  It is also useful to note that $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$ for all $n$.

Then let $A=\cap_{i=1}^n A_n$ using $A_n$ from your definition.

Show that $f(A)=A$.

Finally, if $A$ is empty, show that $\cup_n (X\setminus A_n)$ is an open cover of $X$. Can we find a finite sub-cover of this cover?

(Alternatively, you could also use the sequence definition for compactness in metric spaces. Pick any $x_0\in X= A_0$. Define $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. Then $x_n\in A_n$. The sequence must have a convergent subsequence - show that limit of that subsequence is in $A_n$ for all $n$.)

Comment: Shouldn't you have something like $A= \bigcap _{i = 1}^\infty A_i$ and not $A_n$?

Comment: Why $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$?

Comment: @Thmoas Andrews , can you explain , why $ A _{n+1} $ subset of $ A_n $

Comment: @julien Induction. Or directly, $A_{n+1}=f^{n+1}(X)=f^{n}(f(X))\subseteq f^{n}(X)=A_n$.

Comment: Oh boy...silly me.

Comment: @AnindyaGhatak See my previous comment. Or, by induction. Base case ($n=0$:) $A_1=f(A_0)=f(X)\subseteq X=A_0$. Induction case: If $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$, we can deduce that $A_{n+2}=f(A_{n+1})\subseteq f(A_{n})=A_{n+1}$.

Comment: $ A_n $ satisfy f.i.p property. So $ A $ is nonempty.

Comment: $ Thomas andrews many many thanks for your help.for next I use f.i.p property.

Comment: Ah, just for completeness, the "f.i.p" is the "finite intersection property." A family of subsets satisfies the FIP if any finite set of elements of the set has non-empty subset. There is a dual to the "open cover" property of compactness in terms of collections of closed subsets that satisfy the FIP.